# Python script don't receive exit signal sent by supervisor

Tags: python, signals, tornado, supervisord

I'm running a python script that creates a Tornado server, the server is run by supervisor.
I want to gracefully terminate all WebSocket client connections when a **supervisorctl reload** is issued (normally after a deploy).

My problem is that I'm not able to get a function called when my server is killed by supervisor, but it works when using kill with the signal or run on console and killed with Control+C.
I have tried other signals and configurations without luck.

```
import signal, sys

def clean_resources(signum, frame):
    print "SIG: %d, clean me" % signum
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Nicely handle closing the server
    for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        signal.signal(sig, clean_resources)
```

This is my tornado_supervisor.conf

```
[program:tornado_server]
command = python /opt/tornado/server.py -p 8890
user = www-data
stdout_logfile = /var/log/tornado/tornado_server_sup.log
redirect_stderr = true
autorestart=true
environment=HOME='/var/www'
environment=PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/opt/tornado/"
stopsignal = TERM
stopwaitsecs = 10
stopasgroup = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar/same problem. Only parent Tornado process got the signal, while children processes where not killed.

I made arrangement that parent process kills children manually using os.killpg(), also, children uses some delays to (possibly) finish current requests:

```
#will be initialized in main()
server = None
loop = None

def stop_loop():
    global loop
    loop.stop()

def signal_handler_child_callback():
    global loop
    global server
    server.stop()
    # allow to finish processing current requests
    loop.add_timeout(time.time() + LOOP_STOP_DELAY, stop_loop)

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    global loop
    global server
    if loop:
        #this is child process, will restrict incoming connections and stop ioloop after delay
        loop.add_callback(signal_handler_child_callback)
    else:
        #this is master process, should restrict new incomming connections
        #and send signal to child processes
        server.stop()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_DFL)
        os.killpg(0, signal.SIGTERM)


def main():
  parse_command_line()      
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

  # ...

  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
      [
          #...
      ])

  global server 
  server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
  server.bind(options.port)  
  server.start(0)
  global loop
  loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
  loop.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```